# CodeMirror - Linking DOM Element to Code Lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I am implementing a live HTML code editor and am using codemirror.
My issue is, I am not able to link my code lines with the actual HTML page. Functionality that I want to add is, clicking on an element on the page scrolls the code editor to that particular line in the code.

I was able to do this by adding a unique identifier to the element which clicked and then search for that identifier inside the code editor using the search command. Is there a better way to work this around?

Comment: Can you be little more specific? It'd be great if you could show some code with what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: I have an HTML Page which has a code editor (Codemirror). I have an iframe inside this HTML Page which loads an HTML page (of same domain, so no cross domain issues here). The HTML Code of the iframe is loaded inside the code editor. Clicking on an element inside the iframe should scroll the codemirror to the line which contains the corresponding code (like right click on an element & inspect opens the inspector with the element highlighted).

So right now, when you click on the element, I add a unique class which then I search for inside the code editor to locate the element